# How to put HTML, CSS and JS in one single file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have created a landing page for a client's website. They apparenlty can't upload the folder with the JS files, so they need all the JS and CSS in one same file.

I started putting (before the body section) all the CSS putting it into  and the JS putting in into , but all the animations inside the JS don't work.

Is there any way/advice on how to put it all together?

Thanks!

Ps: I could give more info if needed!

Comment: Are the animations done in jquery? Are you importing any JS libs locally?

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you what's wrong without sharing your code ????

Comment: Welcome to SO! "_I could give more info if needed_": looks like it **is** needed. Please make sure to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your questions.

Comment: Add your code of JS.

Comment: I doubt their inability to upload a folder to their hosting. I'd spend the time you're wasting stuffing all the content in to a single file trying to upload the correct content structure instead

Answer (score -6, accepted):

you cannot save all the file extension into one single file. Css is .css, Javascript is .js.
but you can link all those files into your html

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourcssfile.css">
```

for javascript

```
  <script src="yourjsfile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 17):

You just need to add a style section and a scripts section in the head

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        /* CSS goes here */

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* Javascript goes here */

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would be interesting if there is a Webpack Plugin that does this.

Comment: @Polv did you have further infos for this ?

Comment: Isn't the <script> tag supposed to go after the body?

Comment: @Joel8bitar - it can actually go anywhere and modern browsers will do their thing and render it. In fact, if your script is very large and will delay rendering, it'll be better after as it won't impact the page load time. There's also considerations if your script is manipulating the DOM, as the DOM elements need to exists at he moment the script is ran.  You can handle this before the body using a document onload event, or after the body using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)